# Google Pass script How to run onEdit() when any value is pasted on certain cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run a trigger whenever I paste any values on sheet 'Temp' Cell C2

How can I do this ?

--

This is the code I have

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Temp')return;
  if(e.range.getA1Notation()!='C2')return;
  e.source.toast('You enter: ' + e.range.getValue());

 // what I want to run when any value is pasted on C2
 Script();   
}
```

I want to notice, it works when I copy and paste only in C2 but im taking a whole range, and pasting it , so maybe that's the reason why is not working for me ?, maybe I have to change something that indicates when I paste a range ?

--

This is the script function I want to run when I paste the range

```
function Script(){

  // Gets Temp Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Temp");

  // Change file name
  ss.rename(sh.getRange('Q4').getValue());

  // Hide Sheet "Temp"
  sh.hideSheet();

  // Paste as values dates from sheet Temp
  var range ="AL3:AL5";
  sh.getRange(range).copyTo(sh.getRange(range), {contentsOnly:true})

  // Hides blank rows in sheets 1,2,3
  Hide();

  // Creates the File in Drive
  var sheetId = ss.getId(); 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID"); // The File is stored in this folder
  var name = ss.getName() + ".xlsx"; // The name of the new file  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + sheetId + "/export?format=xlsx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(name); // Modified
  folder.createFile(blob);


  Reset();
}

/*
After the file is generated 
*/

function Reset() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Temp');  

  // Unhide Sheet "Temp"
  sheet.showSheet();

  // Resets Sheet Temp
 sheet.getRange('A1:AI').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('AL3').setFormula('=AL1');
  sheet.getRange('AL4').setFormula('=WORKDAY(AL3,1)');
  sheet.getRange('AL5').setFormula('=WORKDAY(AL4,1)');

  // Reset the file name
  ss.rename('_'+'TEMPLATE');

  // Set the cursor to move to Temp
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Temp'))

  // Unhides Rows from sheets 1,2,3
  Unhide();

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Temp')return;
  if(e.range.rowStart==2 && e.range.columnStart==3) {
    Script();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I just paste any values on C2 it doesn't make the onEdit ... only when I manually type something it does, is there a way to change it, to apply the onEdit when I paste values ?
Also I want to note that C2 is a merged cell C2:L3

Comment: Yes, that sheet is named Temp, I included the e as your code (I added it to the question) , and I don't have any other onedit, just that one, and I created the trigger for onedit

Comment: What is Script()?  If it access user data then onEdit() must be an installable trigger.

Comment: it works when I copy and paste only in C2 but im taking a whole range, and pasting it , so maybe that's the reason why is not working for me ?, maybe I have to change something that indicates when I paste a range ?

Comment: Script() is the script function that I want to run onEdit

Comment: I have added what script function does, and as I mentioned it works when I paste only in C2 but not when I paste a whole range togheter

Comment: Try this new version.  The upper left corner of the paste range must be C2

Comment: Great.  Sorry it took so  long.